# Make flex child equal height of parent inside of grid column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to build a pricing table where each column contains a card. I want all cards to stretch to the height of their parent (.col) elements.

Note: I'm using Bootstrap 4, and trying to achieve this with the existing grid system (for the sake of consistency) **and with this particular piece of markup**. I can't get the cards to grow to the height of their parent containers. Is this even possible with the current markup?

The basic markup is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          blah
          blah
          blah
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          blah
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          blah
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZXWJB

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33636796/3597276

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `flex-grow : 1;` to your `.card` rule. HTML markup is fine.

```
.row {
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  background: #00e1ff;
  margin: -8px;
}
.col { 
  display: flex; 
  flex: 1 0 400px;
  flex-flow: column; 
  margin: 10px;
  background: grey;
}
.card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #002732;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

You may also look at [Foundation 6 Equalizer](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html) plugin. They use JavaScript though.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for that! As a bonus question, is it possible to have all cards remain the same height when they stack? (Guessing not possible without JS)

Comment: Look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/mWeXVV). That's how I would go about it. I'm using jQuery though. Do you need to achieve the same result in pure JS?
I'm not aware of a pure CSS technique to keep track of the biggest height among siblings.

Comment: Thanks Sumi, that's fine - was just curious if such a flex feature existed. JQuery will do.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to add `height: 100%` on `.card`

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #002732;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpqjNy)

Comment: @Naila Flexbox or height?

Comment: @Nenand flexbox property , i think align-items and flex-direction not work with ie9

Comment: This example doesn't actually work for me in desktop Safari - the text overflows out of the container. 'flex-grow: 1'  fixed it for me. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 5):

Just add `flex: 1` to your `card` class. Should be enough. And you don't need `display: flex; align-items: stretch; flex-direction: column` in this class.

Answer (score 2):

To make elements stretch vertically within a .col class using flexbox, simply add inline-style to the .col element:

```
<div style={{alignItems:"stretch"}} class="col">
```

or

add the align-items: stretch; property to the .col class:

```
.col {
    align-items: stretch;
    ...rest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add height: 100% to .card

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #002732;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

example - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZGzyd

Answer (score 0):

Just make your `.card`height to 100%.

```
.card{
   height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   padding: 20px;
   background: #002732;
   color: white;
   opacity: 0.5;
   align-items: stretch;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, they already have build-in classes for what you're trying to achieve.

Add `card-deck` to `<div class="row card-deck">`

[image: here's screenshot]

Comment: I'd be weary of using these as they're not responsive on mobile (not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` on `.col` and `min-height: 100%;` on `.class`

```
.row {
  display: flex; 
  ...
  }
.col { 
  display: inline-block; 
  ...
  }
.card {
  min-height:100%;
  ...
  }`
```